# Trace of an array using intrinsic SUM function in FORTRAN

Tags: arrays, sum, fortran

Is it possible to use the intrinsic SUM function to calculate the trace of an array (of rank > 1)?

Currently, I am using a do loop to calculate trace.

```
trace = 0.0d0
do i = 1, 10
  trace = trace + a(i,i)
end do
```

Comment: I guess you could use the `MASK` parameter, which would require you to generate a mask that is `.TRUE.` only on the diagonal. That said, the creation of the mask itself would probably require a `DO` loop as well.

Comment: You could even use an approach like the one in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16204558/3157076).

Answer (score 6):

**TL/DR**: Your method is fine, use that.

Slightly longer:

1. You can use a mask, but that is less readable, slower, and far more error prone:

   ```
   sum(a, mask = &
      reshape((/ (mod(i, size(a, 1)+1) == 1, i=1, size(a)) /), &
      shape(a) ))
   ```
2. You can use an implied do loop to create a new temporary array of just the diagonal elements:

   ```
   sum( (/ (a(i,i), i=1, size(a, 1)) /) )
   ```

   Again, this is less efficient, as the program has to create a new array, and I don't think that it's more readable than your version.

Comment: could be useful if you are performing the operation repeatedly. You could just build the mask once.

Comment: Even with a pre-made mask it will be slow. The larger the matrix the worse will it be.

Comment: I think what we all agree on is that OPs method is the simplest, fastest, and easiest to understand method of calculating the trace, and they should keep using it.