# Which is the correct way to use pointers remapping?

Tags: pointers, fortran

I want the pointer diagonal to point to the diagonal of a matrix. The code is this:

```
program try

    implicit none

    integer , dimension (3,3), target :: a

    integer, dimension(:, :), pointer :: matrix
    integer, dimension(:), pointer :: diagonal, base

    allocate (base(3*3))
    matrix(1:3, 1:3) => base
    diagonal => base(1:9:4)

    matrix => a

    a=reshape([1, 2, 3,4 ,5, 6, 7, 8, 9],[3,3])

    print *, diagonal

end program try
```

But i get this strange numbers: 17397152  1735357008  1701602145 , instead of 1,5,9. Why is that?

Comment: [This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16203092/3157076) should give you hints.

Answer (score 1):

When you print `diagonal`, it points to `base`, which hasn't been initialised. The numbers `17397152`, `1735357008` and `1701602145` are uninitialised; they just report whatever was in that memory before the program began.

I think the confusion comes from what you're doing with `matrix`. You initially point `matrix` at `base`. You then point `matrix` at `a`. However, this removes the association between `matrix` and `base`, and so when you initialise `a` nothing happens to `base`.

As pointed out by @francescalus, the diagonal can then be pointed to using this answer: [How to assign a pointer to a diagonal of a matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16203092/how-to-assign-a-pointer-to-a-diagonal-of-a-matrix).

I suspect something like this is what you were aiming for:

```
program try

    implicit none

    integer, dimension(3,3), target  :: matrix
    integer, dimension(:),   pointer :: matrix_1d
    integer, dimension(:),   pointer :: diagonal
    
    ! Initialise matrix.
    matrix = reshape([1, 2, 3, 4 ,5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [3, 3])
    
    ! Point a 1D pointer at the 2D matrix.
    matrix_1d(1:9) => matrix
    
    ! Point 'diagonal' at the diagonal elements.
    diagonal => matrix_1d(1:9:4)

    print *, diagonal

end program try
```

Comment: ok. i get an error: rank mismatch in array reference

Comment: I'm trying to understand it sir. But for now i cant get around ot

Comment: thanks @francescalus do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: @DomenicoBianchi I've updated my answer to solve that problem too

Comment: Thank you very much to both. I studied both the solutions. @veryreverie so there is no need to use allocate, then!? I was following a text which also exchanged the right order in the second step, pointing the rank 2 pointer to the rank1 one! Now it makes sense. Thanks

Comment: @DomenicoBianchi if you allocate a pointer you effectively create a new variable, and then point the pointer at that variable. Here you're pointing the pointer at a variable that's already been created, so there is no need to allocate.